# NSString to equation

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using Objective-C and I am trying to set an equation that is stored in an `NSString` to be evaluated and stored in an `NSInteger`.

something similar to the following:

```
equation = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"1+5*6"];
```

and then evaluate that to become 31 and store it into an `NSInteger`. any ideas how to do this?

Comment: What language is the expression in? Is it always constant or does it contain variables?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You want the wonderful, amazing, and fabulous GCMathParser, available (FOR FREE!) on apptree.net:  http://apptree.net/parser.htm  It does exactly what you're asking, and even allows you to do variable substitutions (3x+42, evaluate with x = 7).  It even has support for mathematical functions like sin(), cos(), tan(), their inverses, dtor(), log(), ....

**edit** a long time later...

While GCMathParser is pretty awesome, it has the flaw of not being extensible.  So if you need a function that it doesn't natively support, then too bad.  So I decided to do something about it, and came up with an entirely native math parser and evaluator:  http://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser

Comment: exactly what i needed thatnks!

Comment: Sweet!  I never heard of GCMathParser before.

Answer (score 19):

You can use the predicate system:

```
NSString *equation = @"1+5*6";

// dummy predicate that contains our expression
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                      [equation stringByAppendingString:@" == 42"]];
NSExpression *exp = [pred leftExpression];
NSNumber *result = [exp expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", result); // logs "31"
```

Comment: +1 that's really clever! I like how you add the " == 42" to be able to break it up into expressions.  Does this support any mathematical functions like sin(), cos(), etc?

Comment: This is really interesting.  I had no idea you could do that.  Note that you may need to cast pred as an NSComparisonPredicate (NSExpression *exp = [(NSComparisonPredicate *)pred leftExpression];) to avoid compiler warnings.

Comment: Unfortunately, according to the Predicate Programming Guide, the only supported functions beyond basic arithmetic are sum, count, min, max, average, median, mode, stddev, sqrt, log, ln, exp, floor, ceiling, abs, trunc, random, randomn, and now.  So no trigonometry, I guess.

Comment: @newacct I will try this now, and see how it handles nested parantheses. What's with the == 42? Just a rightExpression to make it an equation, or what?

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson: Yes, just to make it an equation so we can use `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:]`. In Mac OS X 10.6+ and iOS 4+, we can also use `[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:]` directly (this method is not documented, but is defined in the public header file)

Comment: Indeed I had a hard time finding it in docs :) Same for the more serious omission [NSPredicate leftExpression] which raised my eyebrows. I can also confirm that random() and % does not work, but that it handles nested parantheses fine. The random: function looked like more work than it was worth so I ended up search/replacing random()%n with an integer.

Answer (score 7):

I have use this on iPhone to evaluate an equation. It's simpler, you don't need to create a NSPredicate, just the NSExpression:

```
NSString *equation = @"floor((19-10)/2)";
NSNumber *result = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:equation];
NSLog(@"%@", result); // logs "4"
```

And here is the docs to the compatible parseable functions: [“BNF Definition of Cocoa Predicates”](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pBNF.html)

*code shared in Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/3429720)*

Comment: +1 the `+expressionWithFormat:` option was added in Mac OS 10.6 and iOS 4.0.