# Can I calc an equation in Objc at runtime?

Tags: objective-c

Can I do something like this in Objc:

```
NSString* myEquation = @"(3 * 4 / 2 ) - 5";
[myEquation calculate]; // return 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: what does this have to do with javascript?

Comment: OK sorry for that, I've removed the tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://apptree.net/parser.htm should do what you want.

[NSString to equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501949/nsstring-to-equation) The question seems to have been already asked here. So make sure to search first :).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without external libraries: create a predicate with your expression followed by `== 0`, and take its left expression. You can then evaluate that expression, like this:

```
NSExpression *e = [(NSComparisonPredicate *)[NSPredicate
    predicateWithFormat:@"(3 * 4 / 2 ) - 5==0"]
    leftExpression];
NSLog(@"%@", [e expressionValueWithObject:self context:nil]);
```