# Is there an off-the-shelf parser for mathematical expressions in string form?

Tags: objective-c, c, parsing, math

Given the string:

`"10 + 20 - 5 * 7 + (20 / 5)"`

Are there any parsers available that could evaluate this, or would I need to write my own?

Comment: WhatHaveYouTried ? WhereHaveYouSearched ?

Comment: Write a parser and from there it should be trivial. I suggest Haskell.

Comment: Are you working in C, Objective C, or Mathematica?

Comment: @sehe yea, i have to write the links to those great articles down somewhere

Comment: @Minion91 The point is, this one doesn't have to be written down. Also, bookmarks do wonders with autocompletion in the address bar. (I use Opera)

Comment: @sehe nice, didn't know that. Don't need them for auto-completion, just for pasting in comments of bad questions

Comment: @Minion91 Eh. That's what I do. I hit `^L`, searchkeyw, `^A^C <Esc>` and paste!

Comment: @sehe didn't know about ^L either, learning by the minute!

Comment: Hi, thanks for comments and for edit my question. I am working with objective c (iOS) and I've started write my own engine for parse string and calculating result. But I did not search any exist library or framework for this objective. I suppose it already exist. Yes I know that is trivial task, but if in the net's exist already made solution I don't spend my time in creation my own library or something like this.

Comment: There are off-the-shelf parsers that do exactly this. One example is [TinyExpr](https://github.com/codeplea/tinyexpr). It's open-source C. Evaluating your example is a single function call: `te_interp("10 + 20 - 5 * 7 + (20 / 5)", 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1502534/944634) post by [newacct](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86989/newacct).

```
NSString *equation = @"10 + 20 - 5 * 7 + (20 / 5)";

// dummy predicate that contains our expression
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                      [equation stringByAppendingString:@" == 42"]];//42 is just a rightExpression to make it an equation
NSExpression *exp = [pred leftExpression];
NSNumber *result = [(NSComparisonPredicate *)exp expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", result); // logs "-1"
```

Comment: thanks! this is what I was searching.