# Is it possible in swift to convert string, which contains math expression with variables, into closure?

Tags: swift

I've got an expression as a String, for example `x + cos(x) * 5`

How can I convert it into closure like:

```
function: (Double) -> Double = { return $0 + cos($0) * 5 }
```

Maybe `NSExpression` will help?

Comment: It is, but NSExpression doesn't support trig functions. You can add custom functions if you want: http://nshipster.com/nsexpression/. Or maybe find another math expression parser in Swift/ObjC: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1501963/2124535